# Rails json output carrierwave thumbnail version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, thumbnails

I need to render out a **json** output from a controller and I'd like to include the thumbnail version of my images in the json.

If I render json using only `:image_url` it outputs the full image url, if I use `:image` then it will lists all the available images (including thumbnail).

How do I render out in json just the thumbnail version of the image?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use something like this.

```
class ArtworkSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :image_url

    def image_url
      object.image_url(:thumbnail)
    end
  end
```

Then in your JSON response, you will have an attribute `:image_url`.

**Note:** You should have a version defined :thumbnail in your carrierwave uploader.

Comment: Hi Kulking, thanks for your reply, I'm using activemodel_serializer to customize my json output and when I use image_url(:thumbnail) it doesn't work. (It works just fine in the view)

Comment: class ArtworkSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :image_url
end

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to use Serializer like this:

```
class YourSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes(
    :id,
    :image,
    :small,
    :medium,
    :large
  )

  def small
    url(width: 116, height: 116, crop: "fill")
  end

  def medium
    url(width: 640, height: 400, crop: "fill")
  end

  def large
    url(width: 1000, crop: "fill")
  end

  private

  def url(options={})
    options[:format] = "png"
    options[:secure] = true

    object.image_url(options)
  end
end
```

if you goes to stick with thumbnail or already defined version just use:

```
def url
      object.image_url(:thumbnail)
end
```